# How to send an image as an attachment using nodemailer in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, sendgrid, nodemailer

I want to send an email with an attachment using byteArray. The email is getting sent but when I open the attachment received, it says image could not be opened. Where am I making a mistake?

This the calling function:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = 'C:/Users/Downloads/image.jpg'

fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    // Convert the image data into a byte array
    const byteArray = Buffer.from(data);
    const base64Image = byteArray.toString('base64')

    let payload = {
        "to": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "subject": "SUbject",
        "text": "Hi this the body of the email",
        "image": base64Image
    }

    // Example API endpoint to which you want to send the byte array
    const apiUrl = 'https://example.com/api/send';

    let config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: payload,
    }

    // Configure Axios to make a POST request with the byte array
    axios(config).then(response => {
        console.log('API Response:', response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('API Error:', error);
    });
});
```

This is the api end point:

```
const byteArray = Buffer.from(request.body.image)

const mailOptions = {
    from: fromAddr,
    to: request.body.to,
    subject: request.body.subject,
    html: request.body.text,
    attachments: [{
        filename: 'img1.jpg',
        content: byteArray
    }]
}
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: portNo,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        pass: password,
    },
})

transporter
    .sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Sent mail')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error: ')
    })
```

I am however able to send the image as an attachment with bytearray this way:

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Endpoint to send an email
app.post('/send-email', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { to, subject, text } = req.body;
        console.log("req.body = ", req.body)

        const filePath = 'C:/Users/Downloads/image.jpg'

        const emails = ['xyz@gmail.com']

        const html = `
        <h1>Hello world</h1><p>Testing mail</p>
        `;

        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {

            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }

            const byteArray = Buffer.from(data);

            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                port: 465,
                auth: {
                    user: 'mail@gmail.com',
                    pass: password,
                },
            });

            transporter
                .sendMail({
                    from: 'Mail <mail@gmail.com>',
                    to: emails,
                    subject: subject,
                    html: html,
                    attachments: [{
                        filename: 'image.jpg',
                        content: byteArray,
                    }]
                })
                .then((info) => {
                    console.log('Sent mail')
                    console.log(info.accepted)
                    console.log(info.rejected)
                    res.status(200).json({ resp: 'Done'});
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error')
                    res.status(200).json({ error: 'Failed',});
                })

        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error")
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send email' });
    }
});

// Start server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Why does it work this way but not in the other way?

I have been stuck on this for days. I am not sure on how to proceed. Any solution to this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `Buffer.from(request.body.image, "base64")` since you're sending it as base64 - `"image": base64Image`

Comment: @JaromandaX it's working now. Thanks a lot! Since I was encoding it, while decoding I was not using the encoded method. I don't know how I missed that out, it's stupid.